Why is there a huge space after a list in swiftUI?
Whenever I use a List, even if it only has a small amount of items, there is a huge space afterwards. How can I remove the empty space? Here's some example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section("Test"){
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello again")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            
            Text("Hello once more")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


I'm trying to get the Text after the list to be right below the last item of the list, not on the bottom of the screen. I tried putting a spacer after the Text to push it up, but it only does so slightly. I tried having negative padding on the List and Section but that also didn't work.
I found some answers from another question, like don't use a List in the first place; I like how it formats the items, but I suppose I could try that if there are no other solutions.

A list in SwiftUI doesn’t base its height upon the items that it contains by default. It just takes as much vertical space as it can or you can set a static height for it using a frame.
I would think that your choices are:
A) Append your trailing text view to your list’s items so that it appears as the final list item inside the list.  however, this means it will be off the screen if the number of items are large.
B) Put your list inside a vstack along with your trailing text view and set a manual height on that vstack
and also set a background color and/padding on that vstack to make ir appear as a single unit.

So the ScrollView with LazyVStack seems to work just like a list and still has a large space after it, do you have a way to reduce that?

Sorry that was bad advice.

Haha ok, thanks, no problem; I think I'll end up going with your first option, thank you!
